# How was semi-colorization done in Kill Bill?

Tags: film-techniques, kill-bill

In Kill Bill some of the scenes are in partial color with black and white backgrounds and colorized foregrounds. For example, near the end of volume 2, Beatrix is driving to Bill's location and the background is in black and white, but her car is in blue.

How did they achieve this effect?

Comment: Do you mean how this effect was achieved specifially for this firm or how it is achieved *in general*? It's a failrly common technique. Masking out elements has been around for ages.